# iOS weather widget that displays two locations

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, weather.app

Is there an iOS weather widget (for the lock screen) that displays the forecast for two locations at the same time? I'd like to be able to see the weather at home and at my work or other destination at a glance.

It should show at least today's forecasted high, low, and precipitation. I happen to live in Oakland, CA, and work in San Francisco, which are close to each other but have significantly different microclimates, if that's helpful.

(I'm aware that I can download multiple apps and use a different app's widget for each location, but i'd like to use the same app for both locations)

Comment: Maybe you should add details about your location: you are looking for an app that is valid at least in the US?

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about a single iOS app that shows the weather on the lock screen for two locations simultaneously?  I don't have an answer for this exact scenario, but the built-in iOS weather app for iPhones will display the weather for many locations.  You can see the current weather for multiple locations simultaneously, and you can see the forecast for one location at a time and swipe back and forth to see the next or previous locations.

In the weather app, click the menu in the bottom right corner:

[image]

This shows all locations that you've set.  You can see the current weather in all that fit on the screen (as well as if it's day or night). Click the "+" in the lower right to add a new location:

[image]

Then type in the first few letters of the location you want to add:

[image]

Comment: That's not for the lock screen though

Comment: No, it's not, which is why I started my answer by saying I didn't know of an app that met the exact scenario.

Comment: True, you did indeed!